# unable to mount a directory to docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I am running `Mysql` in `Docker` and trying to read a csv file in this location in my local system, and push into a table in the same Mysql db

MYSQL load command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/asha/Documents/2.csv' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

This is where the csv is located in my local system ( Ubuntu 20 )

```
$HOME/Documents/1.csv
```

I am trying to mount this directory into the docker

```
docker run -p 3307:3306 -p 33061:33060 --name=mysql83 -d mysql/mysql-server:latest -v $HOME/Documents:/home
```

Docker doesnt run, this is what i found in docker logs

```
[ERROR] [MY-010147] [Server] Too many arguments (first extra is '/home/asha/Documents:/home').
[ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
```

Is there something wrong with the mount parameters in `docker run` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

you need to put docker run options before the docker image

`docker run -p 3307:3306 -p 33061:33060 --name=mysql83 -d -v $HOME/Documents:/home mysql/mysql-server:latest`